# Cambiar valor de json con un settimeout javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo este json:

```
    let preguntas = {
    respuestas: [
      {
        nombre: "pregunta",
        respuesta: "true",
        puntuacion: "puntuacion",
        estado: "Guardando..",
      },
    ],
  };
```

Para cambiar los valores por ejemplo de nombre realizo esto:

```
preguntas.respuestas[0].nombre = pregunta;
```

Pero quiero que el estado de guardando cambie a los 5 segundos y ponga Listo!!

He tratado de hacer esto:

```
setTimeout(function(){ preguntas.respuestas[0].estado="Listo!!!" }, 5000);
```

Tengo esto dentro de un formulario de este modo:

```
for (var i = 0; i < preguntas.respuestas.length; i++){
      var row = "<tr><td>"+preguntas.respuestas[i].nombre+"</td><td>"+preguntas.respuestas[i].respuesta+"</td><td>"+preguntas.respuestas[i].puntuacion+"</td><td>"+preguntas.respuestas[i].estado+"</td></tr>";

      resultado.innerHTML += row;
      
      Cookies.set("preguntas", row,{expire:30});
    }
Cookies.get("preguntas");
```

Pero en el html se muestra siempre guardando. Se puede hacer esto que quiero realizar? hay alguna alternativa?

**Utilizo Mozilla firefox y una [API](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) para cookies**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente

```js
let preguntas = {
    respuestas: [
      {
        nombre: "pregunta",
        respuesta: "true",
        puntuacion: "puntuacion",
        estado: "Guardando..",
      },
    ],
};

console.log(preguntas.respuestas[0].estado);

setTimeout(() => {
  preguntas.respuestas[0].estado = "¡Listo!";
  console.log(preguntas.respuestas[0].estado);
}, 5000);
```

### Vinculando con HTML

```js
let preguntas = {
    respuestas: [
      {
        nombre: "pregunta",
        respuesta: "true",
        puntuacion: "puntuacion",
        estado: "Guardando..",
      },
    ],
};

statText.innerText = preguntas.respuestas[0].estado;

setTimeout(() => {
  preguntas.respuestas[0].estado = "¡Listo!";
  statText.innerText = preguntas.respuestas[0].estado;
}, 5000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Stat test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p id="statText"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Viendo el código que empleas, no modificas en ningún momento el texto del HTML, por esta razón puede que el texto no cambie a pesar de que el valor del JSON si lo haya hecho.

### Edit

```js
let preguntas = {
    respuestas: [
      {
        nombre: "pregunta",
        respuesta: "true",
        puntuacion: "puntuacion",
        estado: "Guardando..",
      },
    ],
};

for (let i = 0; i < preguntas.respuestas.length; i++){
      const row = "<tr><td>"+preguntas.respuestas[i].nombre+"</td><td>"+preguntas.respuestas[i].respuesta+"</td><td>"+preguntas.respuestas[i].puntuacion+"</td><td class='estado'>"+preguntas.respuestas[i].estado+"</td></tr>";
      resultado.innerHTML += row;
      setTimeout(() => {
        preguntas.respuestas[i].estado = "¡Listo!";
        document.querySelectorAll(".estado").forEach(el => {
          el.innerText = preguntas.respuestas[i].estado
        });
      }, 5000);
}
```

```css
tr,th,td {
  padding:.6rem;
  border:1px solid #c6c6c6c1;
}

body, html {
  font-family: Arial
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <table id="resultado"></table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Usa `querySelector()` para obtener elementos de HTML con selectores de CSS. Debes añadir una clase a todos los TD que contengan el estado, luego con setTimeout esperaremos 5 segundos y cambiaremos el valor del JSON y el texto de todos los TD con la clase "estado" con el nuevo valor del JSON.

Comment: Si bien es la respuesta, seria bueno comunicarle al OP que linea hay que modificar y mostrarle el proceso que se siguio para llegar a la solucion

Comment: Hola!!! muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!!!! lo malo es que creo que si influye es que tengo el resultado dentro de un for debería modificar mi pregunta ya que no consigo areglarlo

Comment: @Twins ¿te funciona ahora?

Comment: disculpa la molestia infinitas gracias!!! si ya funciona!!!!